# vscode abrir carpeta como proyecto de vscode

Tags: windows10, vscode

Al instalar mi vscode me olvidé de activar la opción de habilitar la opción de agregar al menú contextual la opción de abrir una carpeta como un proyecto en el vscode (Sí ya sé F).

Como ya le puse plugins y lo configuré bien bonis la dvd no quiero reinstalar.

¿Cómo puedo programáticamente usar la línea de comandos o algo similar para tener esta opción?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya aprendí que se trata solamente de modificar los registros de windows, así que con el siguiente script basta:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; Abrir archivos
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code]
@="Editar en el dese vscode"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with VS Code\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""

; carpeta
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode]
@="abrir carpeta como proyecto de vscode :v"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%1\""

; Dentro de una carpeta
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode]
@="Abrir como proyecto de vscode >:v"
"Icon"="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\",0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vscode\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" \"%V\""
```

Luego basta con guardarlo con la extensión `.reg`.

Fuente: https://thisdavej.com/right-click-on-windows-folder-and-open-with-visual-studio-code/