# Abrir con code funciona solo en archivos, no en carpetas. Vscode

Tags: vscode, click

Tengo este notebook hace poco, es de segunda mano, sin formatear, y al instalar Vscode me encuentro que la funcion "abrir con code" no funciona en las carpetas, solo en archivos sueltos e incluso aparece en el escritorio, sin clicar algun archivo, la opcion para abrir. hice todo lo que pude, busque info, de hecho aqui mismo en el foro hay una pregunta con respuesta, con la cual no pude solucionar el problema.

Desinstale e instale varias veces, y me asegure al 100% de que las opciones esten tildadas, y nada.

ABRIR CON CODE EN UN ARCHIVO DE ACCESO DIRECTO
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ABRIR CON CODE EN UNA CARPETA
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya muchas gracias, y espero que alguien me ayude.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [vscode abrir carpeta como proyecto de vscode](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/403372/vscode-abrir-carpeta-como-proyecto-de-vscode)

Answer (score 0):

Sitúate en el Powershell en el directorio que quieres abrir y ejecuta la orden

code $PWD

Y se abrirá el VS Code con esa carpeta abierta

Comment: y que tiene que ver esto, con que no le ande la opcion en el boton derecho del menu?

Comment: Como bien dices, no le funciona esa opción, por lo tanto le propongo una forma alternativa de hacer lo mismo